# Как задать отдельные кнопки +/- для input type="number" предпочтительно без использования JS

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Хочу прикрутить отдельные кнопки к стандартному input bootstrap-4 и вот чувствую, что можно обойтись без jqery UI spinner, а вот как не пойму. В документации к bootstrap-4 нашёл только информацию, как отключить стандартные стрелки... Мой код выглядет так:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3 align-self-center">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" min="1" max="999" value="1" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Прошу помочь, в решении задачи.

Comment: без js никак. если это не стандартные

Answer (score 0):

Отказ от разумного JS - это куча "костылей", отсутствие кроссбраузерности, а итог не оправдывает ожиданий...

> Только в качестве примера, как делать не надо!

```css
[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 4px !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
  background: #ff0 !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(9, 10) translate(0, 7px);
  z-index: -10 !important;
}

[type='number']::-webkit-textfield-decoration-container {
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write !important;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: none;
  width: 144px !important;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  padding: 8px !important;
}

div.input-group-prepend,
div.input-group-append {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3 align-self-center">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" min="1" max="999" value="1" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3 align-self-center">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="form-control col-4" min="1" max="999" value="1" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Кое-как работает только в связке WinXP и Chrome49. Разваливается при других вариантах((